# Fixed sidebar anchored between header and footer

Tags: css

I have a sidebar that is `position:fixed` and `height:100%`

However, the effect is not what I desire. The height 100% is 100% of window where as I need to to be 100% of it's container, which is confined between the header and footer. The header is also fixed so the main content scrolls "underneath" it meanwhile the footer is anchored to the bottom of the main content which can be of variable height depending on how much content is loaded.

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27U5n/) I have set the height of the `ul#toolBarList` to `200px` to demonstrate. If you enlarge the window and scroll down, the sidebar should take the full white-space height. I do not mean to simple set a background behind the list, but rather that the bottom of the sidebar should anchor to the top of the footer.

To see why 100% doesn't work, set `200px` to `100%` and witness how the list overflows the footer.

Answer can be some concise javascript or perferably all CSS with compatibility with IE8+, latest chrome/firefox.

Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of all of its parent elements to 100% or just use this CSS instead of the height:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0; //whichever side you want it on
```

Comment: I have tried this in my fiddle and cannot get it to work. Can you show me?

Comment: Here is your example slightly reworked to show the problem again. http://jsfiddle.net/TGw7j/4/ I fixed the header so it doesnt scroll, gave it a height and added a top offset on the #wrapper equal to the height of the header. Then I added a footer with relative position and a height and offset the margin-bottom of #main by the height of the footer. Now everything looks good but the problem is that when scrolling the main content, the side bar scrolls with it. Setting #side to position:fixed  will fix that, but then you're back where I started.

Comment: The side bar is 100% height of its container. What more are you asking?

Comment: Whether or not I asked the wrong question I'm clearly trying to achieve a certain effect where the sidebar is FIXED between the header and footer. I have changed the question, thank you. The sidebar is overflowing onto the footer with the 100% height, that is the problem.

Comment: Yes like that when it is scrolled all the way to the bottom but sticks to the top of the footer when you scroll up.

Comment: You basically want a fixed footer too?

Comment: Nope, the footer is anchored to the bottom of the main content area whose height depends on the number of items in the list. I do not want to take the footer "out of flow". At this point I'm pretty convinced this can only be done with a little js, which I'm open to as I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

100% height only works when the parent element has an explicit height set. You can achieve 100% height by setting 100% height on the html element, body element, and any other container elements in between. For example,

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
  <body style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="page" style="height: 100%;">
      <div id="sidebar" style="height: 100%; float: left;">content</div>
      <div id="main" style="height: 100%; float: left;">content</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here's your suggestion not working http://jsfiddle.net/Cn29j/  And besides, I cannot set #page or #main in your example to 100% because #main has dynamic height depending how much content is loaded

Comment: 100% does not mean the screen height, it means the document height, therefore the dynamic height is unaffected.